# firebase functions upload file from web via stream only partially working

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, axios, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to create a firebase function that downloads a photo off the web via URL and uploads it to firebase storage.

Using Axios to stream the file to the bucket. it appears the file gets uploaded but i cant download or view it.

This is my code:

```
let fileURL = 'https://www.example.file.path.png'

let myFile = await axios.get(fileURL, { responseType: 'stream' })
let destFile = bucket.file(photoId).createWriteStream({ contentType: myFile.headers['content-type']})
myFile.data.pipe(destFile)
```

And here is the storage console from firebase:
[image]

I have messed around with the storage api and attempted using the upload and save functions. using axios get and write streams is the closest that I'v got to getting this to work.

Reading the [example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/extend-with-functions#example_image_transformation) in the docs only aids in my confusion because the file is never reference in the upload function.. just the file name??

Feel like i'm almost there considering the file or rather the name of the file is there and the size and the type.. just not the content?

Comment: You're not using the node stream api correctly.  pipe() doesn't return a promise.  Might want to review the documentation for that: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html

Comment: What is happening when you try to download it?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is related with Firebase console only. There is no problem with downloading with command: `gsutil cp gs://<your bucket>/yourfile .` ([doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp)) and as well it is working in Google Cloud Console in Storage browser ([direct link](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser)).

However indeed file uploaded like this is not possible to be downloaded or previewed with Firebase console.

After many tries I have realized that this is related with custom metadata `Access token`, which underneath is called`firebaseStorageDownloadTokens`. It appears automatically if ex. you download the file directly in Firebase console.

Anyway I noticed that value of the metadata is irrelevant. According to my test if you change your `createWriteStream` method parameters to:

```
let destFile = bucket.file(photoId)
                .createWriteStream({ 
                        metadata: { 
                                contentType: myFile.headers['content-type'],
                                metadata: {
                                        firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: 'canBeAnyThing'
                                }
                        } 
                });
```

The problem disappears...

A file already downloaded to Firebase Storage and affected by the issue can be fixed by adding the same metadata. In the screenshot you have provided you can see "File Location" if you open you will see link "*Create new access token*" or as well you can add it in GCP Storage Browser adding it manually in  "Edit metadata" for such object (remember to refresh FB console in browser).

At this point we can think of why it's looks like this. I have found interesting information in github [here](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/issues/34#issuecomment-541694437).